# Flutter using cloud_firestore giving errors on IOS Simulator

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

It's my first time trying to use Firebase cloud_firestore together with Flutter. It works fine with the Android emulator. But I am getting the following errors, when trying to Run on the IOS Sim:

```
/Users/carsoncarbery/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:50:22: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'queryWhereField:arrayContains:'
query = [query queryWhereField:fieldName arrayContains:value];
~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/carsoncarbery/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:221:29: error: no known class method for selector 'fieldValueForArrayUnion:'
return [FIRFieldValue fieldValueForArrayUnion:[self readValue]];
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/carsoncarbery/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:224:29: error: no known class method for selector 'fieldValueForArrayRemove:'
return [FIRFieldValue fieldValueForArrayRemove:[self readValue]];
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
8 warnings and 3 errors generated.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 6s.
```

I've also tried running the Runner directly from Xcode and get the same three build errors. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find an answer to this, so am posting the question. Any help would be gratefully received.
Thanks

Comment: is your GoogleService-Info.plist in ios/Runner folder?

Comment: Yes, its in the ios/Runner folder

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same thing.
Following these guys
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24395

I did

```
pod update Firebase/Firestore
```

And it worked for me.
I'm using latest version of cloud firestore: 0.9.0+1
I can compile from both Xcode and VS Code.
There are a lot of warning messages when running on simulator. some of them look pretty nasty, but it works.