# Xcode build error from Firebase pod: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRAuth'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I just pulled from a working version and cannot build my project due to what looks like a `cocopods` error

**What I've Tried**

- I followed this tutorial which usually seems to work and it did not work: [Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'](http://Quit%20Xcode.%20Delete%20project%27s%20temp%20files%20located%20at%20%7E/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData%20Delete%20ProjectName.xcworkspace%20Delete%20Podfile.lock%20file%20and%20Pods%20folder%20Run%20pod%20install.%20Open%20the%20newly%20created%20ProjectName.xcworkspace%20file%20and%20build.)

> Quit Xcode.
> Delete project's temp files located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
> Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
> Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder
> Run pod install.
> Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.

I also udpated jsut the Firebase/Firestore pods with
`pod update Firebase/Firestore`
 [cloud_firestore giving errors on IOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019347/flutter-using-cloud-firestore-giving-errors-on-ios-simulator)

- I also tried manually updating the Firebase pod version with `pod 'Firebase/Core', '~>5.20.2'`
  Then `pod install` This crashed during pod install.
- I also just tried `pod update` this did not resolve anything.
- I also cleaned by Xcode build folder and rebuild the project after updating the pods and still received the same error.

```
- (void)useEmulatorWithHost:(NSString *)host port:(NSInteger)port {
  [self.auth useEmulatorWithHost:host port:port];
  self.emulatorEnabled = YES;
}
```

Error:

```
error: no visible @interface for 'FIRAuth' declares the selector 'useEmulatorWithHost:port:'
  [self.auth useEmulatorWithHost:host port:port];
   ~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same issue :/

Comment: @CharlesVanDamme this was a long time ago so I do not remember. If you are getting these kinds of errors it is most certainly a pod issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Delete Pods folder from Project by going into Folder explorer
- Clear Project in Xcode
- pod deintegrate
- pod init
- pod cache clean --all
- pod update

Comment: dosn't work still exist

Answer (score 0):

I updated cocoapods with `sudo gem install cocoapods` and then I updated the project `pod update` and everything works again. It seems some firebase pods are not compatible with old version of cocoapods and you are not getting the last version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift' as a cocoapod, I had to swap over to using: `pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '= 7.5.0-beta'` instead. Do that and then just do a `pod update` and see if it helps. Answer found here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/938